# Cannot Retrieve Table Rows collection in DOM using FireFox

Tags: javascript, dom

I have had a problem in firefox (using 10.0.2) trying to use javascript to retrieve the rows in a table.  The following work in Chrome and IE, but not in firefox.

```
var tbl = "myTable";
var allTR;
allTR = document.getElementById(tbl).childNodes[0].childNodes;

var table = document.getElementById(tbl);
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
allTR = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
allTR = tbody.children;
allTR  = tbody.childNodes;
allTR = $("#myTable").find("tbody").find("tr");
allTR = $('#myTable tobdy tr');
```

In Firefox, the resulting allTR object shows up in Firebug as "undefined" even though I can see that it has a length property.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: A demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful

Comment: Making JavaScript deal with all the different browsers is a huge pain.  If at all possible, start using a library like jQuery.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Not usually necessary. It's easier than you might think.

Comment: How many different versions of IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera are there?

Comment: @SteveWellens: Lots. However, the vast majority of them follow existing standards precisely, particularly 12-year-old ones such as DOM 2.

Comment: Because the program is close to a code freeze, my boss did not want me to start putting in another jquery plug-in (note that one of the examples above did use jquery).  As I commented below, a static table test I did worked perfectly, so I suspect that the issue in FF is due to the fact that the table was created at runtime using an Ajax call and client side JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want all the rows in a table:

```
allTR = document.getElementById(tbl).getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

if you want the rows in the first tbody:

```
allTR =document.getElementById(tbl).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')
```

Comment: If you look at the example I provided, I was already using this code and it was failing.  Tomalak asked me to put an example in jsFiddle.  I created the test code locally in preparation for posting it and it of course, worked fine. My suspicion now is that FireFox does not play well with tables that are created dynamically.  My particular problem is tied to a table generated at runtime using an ajax call and clientside JS.

Comment: @Kberg59: Why is this better than my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely to me that your table may have some empty white space nodes that you're not considering. IE < 9, for example, does not reflect white space text nodes in its DOM, while all other major browsers do, meaning that `table.childNodes[0]` may well not be what you think it is.

The simplest solution is to use the convenient and universally supported DOM table properties such as `rows`:

```
var allTR = document.getElementById("myTable").rows;
```

There is also a convenient `cells` property of `<tr>` elements, should you require it. `<tbody>` elements also have a `rows` property.